# Dark ActionBar but Light PopMenu

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I have a red actionbar and I'm using the DarkActionBar theme. But what I want is the popup menu in light colors. What I'm trying right now is something like this:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
</style>
```

But the background of the menu is always black (I tried some other aproaches). I don't want to change it to Light ActionBar because the icon of the DarkActionBar fits bettes with the red color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was able to solve it by myself. I have now a Light ActionBar but I changed the menu icon and the behavior of the focused items on the actionbar.

Here's what I did:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyButtonOverflow</item>
        <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/item_background_holo_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyButtonOverflow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark</item>
    </style>
```

I had to copy some resources of the android platform res folder, for example:

res/drawable/item_background_holo_dark.xml
res/drawable/list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark.xml

and some .9.png